# PHP Find two consecutive numeric entries in array

Tags: php

My problem is it just replicates the number twice, though it does add the break when there is a number, but I'm trying to check if there is a number after the number, so it would say line 12 is.....

Thanks for any help

```
<?PHP
$lines =  file_get_contents('http://www.webstitcher.com/test.txt');
$tag = str_split($lines); // puts all lines into a array
foreach ($tag as $num => $letta){
    if (is_numeric($letta) == TRUE){
        $num2 = $num++;
        if (is_numeric($tag[$num2])){ // checks if next line is going to be another digit
        $letta .= $tag[$num2];
        unset($tag[$num2]); // removes line if it had another digit and adds to ouput
        }
            echo '<br />' . $letta;
        } 
        else {
    echo $letta;
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: not clear from your question what the input is or the desired output

Comment: Your question title should have been "Find two consecutive numeric entries in array". (The question text is somewhat incomprehensible). -- The problem lies in `$num++` btw.

Comment: `str_split` is not splitting a string by new line... so the comment is not matching the code. same for the other two comments. there are no lines. it's just one in the example

Comment: str_split puts every letter into an array, and then I get it to start a new line if it is a number, but I need to check for 10 ect, so that 10 will be output, so I need to check for the next array value and see if it is a number, than add the number to the array, unset that value so it doesn't get printed

Comment: Are you trying to replace numbers with line breaks? Is that what the aim of the code is?

Comment: in the end I will put it in a database by the numbers.

1-blablalba
....
22-blablabla

22 would come out
2
2-blablabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exploding the string using `' '` as the delimiter. This will allow you to keep the numbers whole and will ultimately help cut out a lot of the complexity.

```
$lines =  file_get_contents('http://www.webstitcher.com/test.txt');
$tag = explode(' ', $lines); // puts all words into a array
foreach ($tag as $word){
    if (is_numeric($word)) {
        // if the word is numeric, simply skip to next line
        // if you need to keep the number, add $word to the echo statement
        echo '<br />';
    } 
    else {
        echo ' '.$word;
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to keep track of the previous element in the array or check for the next element.

---

Alternatively, you could also use `preg_replace` which would remove the need for the loop entirely.

```
$lines = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '<br>', $words);
```

Comment: This code will strip out the numbers and print the text, which is completely unrelated to what OP was asking for: *I'm trying to check if there is a number after the number*

Comment: @Aydin, yes, because the string is split into individual characters such that `666` gets split into `['6', '6', '6']`. The goal of the algorithm is to use the numbers as line delimiters, which is what I am doing here. I'll edit to include the number in the ouptput though

Comment: *The goal of the algorithm is to use the numbers as line delimiters* - then why won't you simply preg_replace the numbers with line breaks?

Comment: @Aydin That would also work, I was concentrating on simplifying the code at hand, but that's another great option